# Change date format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

In JavaScript:

```
var todayDate = new Date();
```

How to convert the actual date to this format (example):

```
Mon Aug 25 2014
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`toDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) gives you exactly that format.

```
var todayDate = new Date();
todayDate.toDateString(); // "Thu Aug 14 2014"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugins like Moment.js or you can just `...todayDate.getDay() + ' ' + todayDate.getFullYear()`